# Modal view screen before login view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a newbie ios developer and i had a question on how to add a view to a login page. Currently i have a login page and what i want to do is before the login page is visible, another modal view should preceed it that the user must first dismiss. How can i add this in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple options for presenting a view controller.

```
- (IBAction)goToLoginView:(id)sender
{
     //if you are using xibs use this line
     UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     //if you are using storyboards use this line
     UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllersID"];

     //to present the controller modally use this
     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
     //or if you are pushing to this controller using a navigation controller use this
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Then to dismiss a view controller use this:

```
- (IBAction)closeMyController
{
    //if the view was presented modally close it with this
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //and to pop back up the navigation stack
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: um how excatly do you even create the view in xcode?. I cant seem to do that and get all three .m,.h and .xib files...

Comment: @JohnBaum Do you want to create a UIView, or a UIViewController?

Comment: Im not really sure what the difference is. I want to create a popup view once the app is loaded to the login view. So within the login view .m file, i want to initiate the modal dialog for a welcome greeting

Comment: @JohnBaum The code I have provided should fit your needs, the only other thing I can think of that behaves this way that you might be talking about is a UIAlertView.